# Not able to capture request response for CRM Dynamics 365 app using Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, dynamics-crm, performance-testing

While system proxy is set with Jmeter, CRM Dynamics 365 app is prompting for credentials repeatedly until it gives "HTTP 401.1 - Unauthorized: Access is denied" error at last. Without the proxy, users can access the CRM application at ease over browsers. Following steps are already taken, but no luck yet.

- Jmeter root certificate is installed
- Domain admin credentials are used for login
- For authentication, NTLM service provider is set at IIS

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Hi, thanks for responding. The request actually could not be recorded in Jmeter as the application was repeatedly asking for credentials over proxy. As part of the scenario, authentication is a must, so without proxy is not a viable option. Changing the setting in advanced didn't work as the request has to be captured for the settings change - which is not working in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

In recorder advanced tab , switch Http request implementation to Java and try again.

If it doesn’t work, investigate wether it’s ntlm or keeberos.

Alternatively you can start authenticating without proxy setuo and once done, you switch browser to use jmeter proxy.

Answer (score 0):

You can record test cases over BlazeMeter then import them into JMeter. That is worked for me.